# Columns change format when a row is added to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I add a row to the DataFrame and when I call describe it doesn't output numeric summary values any more.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
myDataset = {"Movie Title":          ['Avengers: Endgame',    'Avatar',    'Titanic',  'The Lion King'],
            "Gross":                 [         2797800564,  2790439000,   2194439542,       1656943394],
            "Rotten Tomatos Rating": [                 94,          82,           89,               53],
            "Year":                  [               2019,        2009,         1997,             2019],
            "Length":                [                181,         162,          194,              118]                        
            }
print ("Original Data...")
df = pd.DataFrame(myDataset)
print(df.describe())

# Add a column
df['Seen It'] = [False, False, True, False]
print ("After adding the column...")
print(df.describe())

# Add a row
newRow = pd.Series(np.array(["Hoosiers", 29000000, 89 , 1986, 116, True]), 
                   index=["Movie Title", "Gross", "Rotten Tomatos Rating", "Year", "Length", "Seen It" ])
row_df = pd.DataFrame([newRow])

newDF = df.append(row_df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print ("After adding a row...")
print(newDF.describe())
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just change the format of the new dataframe that you try to append, by rather than creating a new `df` in long format (with `index`), give it the column names, by passing a list in the argument`columns=["Movie Title", ...]`

```
newRow = pd.DataFrame([["Hoosiers", 29000000, 89 , 1986, 116, True]],
                      columns=["Movie Title", "Gross", "Rotten Tomatos Rating", "Year", "Length", "Seen It" ])
newDF = df.append(newRow, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Output of describe:

```
              Gross  Rotten Tomatos Rating         Year      Length
count  5.000000e+00               5.000000     5.000000    5.000000
mean   1.893724e+09              81.400000  2006.000000  154.200000
std    1.145114e+09              16.440803    14.387495   35.821781
min    2.900000e+07              53.000000  1986.000000  116.000000
25%    1.656943e+09              82.000000  1997.000000  118.000000
50%    2.194440e+09              89.000000  2009.000000  162.000000
75%    2.790439e+09              89.000000  2019.000000  181.000000
max    2.797801e+09              94.000000  2019.000000  194.000000
```

Check the dtypes of row_df (`row_df.dtypes`) to see the source of this problem. Thus append converts all columns to object (string)

```
Out[43]: 
Movie Title              object
Gross                    object
Rotten Tomatos Rating    object
Year                     object
Length                   object
Seen It                  object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by appending an `np.array` with mixed datatypes (therefore `object`) you are converting the internal datatype of the numerical columns in the DataFrame from `numpy.int64` to `object`.

Comment: I'm not appending an np.array, I'm appending a DataFrame.

Comment: Yes but your DataFrame is constructed with an `np.array` with mixed values, that's why it's changing the underlying datatypes of the DataFrame it's being appended to. You can verify this yourself by calling `dtypes` on the df before and after appending